# Ionic 3 POST request to Laravel

Tags: laravel, post, ionic-framework, ionic3, csrf

I use Cors in laravel, my cors.php is

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Middleware;

 use Closure;

 class Cors
 {
  /**
  * Handle an incoming request.
  *
  * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
  * @param  \Closure  $next
  * @return mixed
  */
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
  {
   return $next($request)
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, 
    OPTIONS');
    header('Content-Type:application/json; charset=utf-8');

  }
}
```

Page root is in laravel web.php;

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'cors'], function()
{
 Route::get('/news_json', 'PagesController@news_json');
 Route::post('/post_request', 'PagesController@post_request');
});
```

Now, in my ionic app; When I post data this get error. Error.status is '419'. I dont use csrf_token in ionic app.
I have a function in ionic;

```
getToken() {
 let token = document.querySelector('meta[property="csrf-token"]')
 ['content'];
  return token;
}
```

I use meta property in ionic3/src/index.html , this meta propery is;

```
  <meta property="csrf-token" name="csrf-token" content="{{ 
  csrf_token() }}">
```

My submit function in ionic ;

```
  var encrypt = new Encrypt.JSEncrypt();
  encrypt.setPublicKey(pubkey);

  var link ='http://172.16.1.19/post_request';
  var myData = JSON.stringify({name: this.data.name, telephone: this.data.telephone, email: this.data.email, ask: this.data.ask});
  var encrypted = encrypt.encrypt(myData);
  var post = {form: encrypted, type: 'baskan'};

  var options = new RequestOptions({headers: new Headers({
    'Content-Type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'X-CSRF-TOKEN': this.getToken()
  })

});
this.http.post(link, post, options).then((data) => {
  this.toast.create({
    message: `İsteğiniz başarıyla gönderildi!.`,
    duration: 3000
  }).present();
  this.data.name="";
  this.data.telephone="";
  this.data.email="";
  this.data.ask="";
}, error =>{
    this.data.ask = error.status;
});
```

I post to laravel other script but when I post data with ionic ı get a error, this error.status is '419' . Can you help me please ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must add your post location in App/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php ;

```
    protected $except = [
    '/post_request',
];
```